# how to change cron table from svn?

Tags: git, unix, svn, cron

is there a way to update cron table with a file from svn or git?

instead of calling

```
crontab -e
```

and manually changing tables I'd like to check in those changes and have crontab pick it up.

Is this possible?

Comment: `ls -la /var/spool/cron/crontabs/`

Comment: @zerkms: It's far better IMHO to use the `crontab` command rather than messing around with `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/`. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this IMHO is to keep your crontab in a file that you maintain in a source control system (SVN, Git, whatever), and then install by invoking the `crontab` command on that file.

Personally, I just do that manually. I don't change my crontab often enough that it's really worth automating the process. I suppose you could configure some kind of hook in your source control system to invoke `crontab` on the file automatically when you check it in (the details will depend on which source control system you use), but I've never bothered.

This has some considerable advantages over `crontab -e`, which I rarely if ever use. It means that if I accidentally mess something up, I can always go back to a previous working version of my crontab, and I can see exactly what I've changed. With `crontab -e`, if you make a mistake, there's no record of the previous version.

It also means you can make temporary experimental changes, either using `crontab -e` or

```
crontab -l > mycron.txt
vi mycron.txt
crontab mycron.txt
```

without the risk of permanently losing any information; you can just run `crontab` on your source-controlled file when you're done experimenting.

Your crontab is probably stored in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER`. I *don't* recommend directly putting that file under version control. Doing so could interfere with the system's handling of the file, and those files are accessible only to `root`; you can run `crontab filename` from your own user account. (In general, don't do anything as `root` that you don't actually *need* to do as `root`.)

Comment: Thanks Keith! To keep things simple I can have a cronjob running crontab <filename> command once a day. Any changes will be then automatically picked up.